# How can Google Analytic Cookies appear without using Analytics?

Tags: php, javascript, cookies

I have never used Google Analytics on my web site.

I have recently implemented an online booking system that I wrote using JavaScript and PHP.

My PHP code includes a "trace" which logs certain data and events related to my application. There is a separate trace log for each user session. The trace includes a list of the cookies and their values that are available.

I have discovered a single instance where cookies named utma, utmb, utmz, ld893_bl and utmc were present in a user session.  I found that the utm.. cookies belong to Google Analytics. (Still no idea what the ld903_bl cookie is.)

My question is this:

Since my web page includes only my JavaScript, and my code does not set these cookies, how can the cookies exist for my domain?

mah

Addendum from trace:

User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)

--- COOKIES ---

mahAvailabilityDate : D20130615z-0500P01

mahMode : V01M0400a0000h137394118225684859002

__utma : 208741518.729017776.1373940236.1373940236.1373940236.1

__utmb : 208741518.0.10.1373940236

__utmz : 208741518.1373940236.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)

ld893_bl : 1373940485

__utmc : 208741518

--- END COOKIES ---

The mah prefix cookies are mine.  The others are a mystery. Theoretically, they can not be there.

Comment: did the domain existed before with GA installed?

Comment: remove all cookies, and cache and try again...

Comment: Have owned domain since 1997. Have just upgraded my host service, so fresh install of whole web site. Is not happening on my PC. cannot reproduce. Found it in trace of 1 John Q Public access to my system.